# C++ : the url reader function doesn't work for URL links with \ sign. pls help me

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wininet

As written in the title, this is a function which returns the HTML source code string of a URL.

It works only with the main page, such as `"finance.yahoo.com/"`. If I try a URL from one of the bookmarks in Yahoo, such as `"finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/"`, it doesn't work.

```cpp
string getHtml() {

    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, " finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

    HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "GET", "/", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);

    char buf[2048];
    string lol;
    HttpSendRequestA(hData, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    DWORD totalBytesRead = 0;
    int i = 0;
    string n, n2;

    while (InternetReadFile(hData, buf, 2000, &bytesRead) && bytesRead != 0)
    {
        buf[bytesRead] = 0; // insert the null terminator.

        // puts(buf);          // print it to the screen.
        lol = lol + buf;
        n = lol;
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(hData);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnection);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: _"... it wouldn't work..."_ - Is anything returned at all, if so what ?

Comment: Aside from the complete lack of error handling (why?), I don't really see much else wrong with this code. But it is requesting the "main page" of `coinbase.com`, which you said works fine. Can you provide a better example of a URL that *doesn't* work fine? Are you accounting for the fact that `finance.yahoo.com` runs on HTTPS not HTTP, thus port 443 rather than 80, and the need for the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag? Actually, the same is true for `coinbase.com`, too

Comment: dear  Richard Critten: @RichardCritten
 no, the function didnt reached the URL. the string which gets the html source code was left with NULL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
dear friend, you are right, with main page of coinbase the function works.

here is an example of when it doesnt work: (I have characters limit so I added the first few lines. the rest of the program is the same as above)


string getHtml() {
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, " finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code that does not work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja 

dear friend, I edited my main Question and changed the URL in line number 3, to the one which didnt work. to make it easier on you guys.
thanks in advance

Comment: @RemyLebeau

dear friend, I edited my main Question and changed the URL in line number 3, to the one which didnt work. to make it easier on you guys.
I saw your comment and tried it in my Vs2019 but I'm not sure how to compleate the "..." , may you please help me sir.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```cpp
HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, " finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "GET", "/", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
```

You can't "connect" to a URL like that, only to a hostname.

You need to specify just the hostname in `InternetConnectA()`, and then specify the desired document relative to that hostname in `HttpOpenRequestA()`.

Also, `finance.yahoo.com` uses HTTPS, not HTTP, so you need to connect to the HTTPS port and use secure semantics on the request.

Try this:

```cpp
HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "finance.yahoo.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "GET", "/quote/BTC-USD/", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
```